# Upload graphic file to devops for use in markdown

Tags: azure-devops

I need to show a traffic light image in a dashboard in devops. I have the .png file in my hard drive.

What is the best way to upload this kind of file to devops?
Is there a folder where I can upload files?

I'm just using "boards" (e.g. not using "repos" feature)

Comment: `Boards` or `Dahsboards` in `Overview` section?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej You're right, it's Dashboards. What I want to state is that I don't have the repository provided by Repos. Is there any other file system where to upload files (that are not code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could access wiki, you can click 'Insert a file' icon in the wiki page editor to select image from your hard drive. Then you'll see the image there.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#images

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?